# Different libraries depend on the same library and will prompt "Duplicate class" during compilation. How to exclude this duplicate class?

Tags: android, gradle

error like this：

```
Duplicate class com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.AspectRatioFrameLayout found in modules jetified-VideoPlayModule-Lite-2.3.61-runtime.jar (com.ycjiang:VideoPlayModule-Lite:2.3.61) and jetified-exoplayer-ui-2.12.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.12.1)

Duplicate class com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.AspectRatioFrameLayout$1 found in modules jetified-VideoPlayModule-Lite-2.3.61-runtime.jar (com.ycjiang:VideoPlayModule-Lite:2.3.61) and jetified-exoplayer-ui-2.12.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.12.1)
```

gradle:

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.12.1'
    implementation 'com.ycjiang:VideoPlayModule:2.3.61'
```